# django {% inlcude %} throws Template Error

Tags: django, django-templates

The problem: I have a file `base.html`, where I have a `{% block content %}`, for the page's content and a `{% inlcude %}`, for the navigation bar (bootstrap) of the base template. But the include does not find the Template (`TemplateDoesNotExist`) and I am sure I didn't spell it wrong. Do I have to provide anything for the template to be found or what?

base.html important content:

```
<body>
    {% include "navbar.html" %}

    <div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Some important information:
I downloaded bootstrap in the base.html file; base.html and navbar.html are in the same folder.

[image]

Comment: Can you update question with your directory structure.

Comment: Also check your settings.py for TEMPLATES list.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha what do I have to add there?

Comment: even if the template is in same directory, it will start searching with respect to base dir. In your directory structure, inside template you have home. so you can change {% include "navbar.html" %} to {% include "home/navbar.html" %} and check if it works for you.

Comment: Also you can check this documentation for understanding of how overriding template works...  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/

Comment: Thx! home/navbar.html worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your directory structure, you have home directory inside templates. Please change code as per below :

```
<body>
    {% include "home/navbar.html" %}

    <div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```